# How to stop flickering in layered image animation

Tags: delphi, vcl

i used 30 png pictures on a transplanted from to make a simple animation, a Timer make an event every 33 Millisecond to change the visibility of the TImage Components which have the png images, i tried all the method suggested in other posts to stop flickering but could not solve the problem.

```
unit Animation;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, AdvShaper, pngimage, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

type
  TAnimation_Form = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    Timer: TTimer;
    Image2: TImage;
    Image3: TImage;
    Image4: TImage;
    Image5: TImage;
    Image6: TImage;
    Image7: TImage;
    Image8: TImage;
    Image9: TImage;
    Image10: TImage;
    Image11: TImage;
    Image12: TImage;
    Image13: TImage;
    Image14: TImage;
    Image15: TImage;
    Image16: TImage;
    Image17: TImage;
    Image18: TImage;
    Image19: TImage;
    Image20: TImage;
    Image21: TImage;
    Image22: TImage;
    Image23: TImage;
    Image24: TImage;
    Image25: TImage;
    Image26: TImage;
    Image27: TImage;
    Image28: TImage;
    Image29: TImage;
    Image30: TImage;
    Exit: TButton;
    procedure TimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ExitClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    Image_Counter:Integer;

    procedure ChooseImage(I:Integer);
    procedure Init();
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;


procedure Run_Animation_Form();
procedure Finish_Animation_Form();

implementation
var
  Animation_Form: TAnimation_Form;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure Finish_Animation_Form();
Begin
  Animation_Form.Close;
End;

procedure Run_Animation_Form();

Begin
  Animation_Form := TAnimation_Form.Create(nil);
  Try
    Animation_Form.Init();
    Animation_Form.ShowModal();
  Finally
    Animation_Form.Free;
  End;
End;

{ TAnimation_Form }

procedure TAnimation_Form.ChooseImage(I: Integer);
begin
  TwinControl(FindComponent(Format('Image%d',[I]))).Visible := False;
  TwinControl(FindComponent(Format('Image%d',[I+1]))).Visible := True;
end;

procedure TAnimation_Form.ExitClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

procedure TAnimation_Form.Init;
begin
  TransparentColor := True;
  TransparentColorValue := Color;
  Image1.Visible := True;
  Image_Counter:=1;
  ControlStyle:=ControlStyle - [csOpaque];
  BorderWidth := 10;
  Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akBottom, akRight];

end;

procedure TAnimation_Form.TimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Image_Counter >= 30 then
    Begin
      Image30.Visible := False;
      Image1.Visible := True;
      Image_Counter:=1;
    End
  else
    Begin
      ChooseImage(Image_Counter);
      Inc(Image_Counter);
    End;

end;

end.
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad English

Comment: This is a very bad way of making an animation.

Comment: I am new to programming, any suggestion about making an animation in delphi will be appreciated

Comment: `Exit: TButton;`: Never give a component (or a routine for that matter) a name which is already declared elsewhere. You should try to prevent the need to qualify syntax and to minimize confusion for yourself, your team members and your code users.

Comment: A nice speaking name for that button: `Exit_Button` OnClick-Method will be renamed in `Exit_ButtonClick`. There you should call a form method `DoExit` and put all code to exit in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using multiple overlapping `TImage` objects and swapping their `Visible` property, I would suggest you create an array of 30 `TPNGImage` objects and then either:

1. use a single `TImage` that is always visible and assign the desired PNG to its `TImage.Picture` property whenever the `TTimer` elapses:

   ```
   unit Animation;

   interface

   uses
     Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
     Dialogs, AdvShaper, pngimage, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

   type
     TAnimation_Form = class(TForm)
       Image1: TImage;
       Timer: TTimer;
       Exit: TButton;
       procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
       procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
       procedure TimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
       procedure ExitClick(Sender: TObject);
     private
       { Private declarations }
       Image_Counter: Integer;
       Images: array[0..29] of TPNGImage;
     public
       { Public declarations }
     end;

   procedure Run_Animation_Form();
   procedure Finish_Animation_Form();

   implementation

   var
     Animation_Form: TAnimation_Form = nil;

   {$R *.dfm}

   procedure Finish_Animation_Form();
   Begin
     if Animation_Form <> nil then
       Animation_Form.Close;
   End;

   procedure Run_Animation_Form();
   Begin
     Animation_Form := TAnimation_Form.Create(nil);
     Try
       Animation_Form.ShowModal();
     Finally
       FreeAndNil(Animation_Form);
     End;
   End;

   { TAnimation_Form }

   procedure TAnimation_Form.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   var
     I: Integer;
   begin
     for I := Low(Images) to High(Images) do
     begin
       Images[I] := TPNGImage.Create;
       // load PNG image into Images[I] as needed...
     end;

     // FYI, these properties can be set at design time...
     TransparentColor := True;
     TransparentColorValue := Color;
     Image1.Visible := True;
     BorderWidth := 10;
     Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akBottom, akRight];

     Image_Counter := 0;
     Image1.Picture := Images[0];

     ControlStyle := ControlStyle - [csOpaque];
   end;

   procedure TAnimation_Form.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
   var
     I: Integer;
   begin
     for I := Low(Images) to High(Images) do
       Images[I].Free;
   end;

   procedure TAnimation_Form.ExitClick(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     Close;
   end;

   procedure TAnimation_Form.TimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     Inc(Image_Counter);
     if Image_Counter > High(Images) then
       Image_Counter := 0;
     Image1.Picture := Images[Image_Counter];
   end;

   end.
   ```
2. use a single `TPaintBox` and assign an `OnPaint` event handler to it that draws the current PNG onto the `TPaintBox.Canvas`, and then have the `TTimer` simply update the current PNG and call `TPaintBox.Invalidate()` to trigger a repaint:

   ```
   unit Animation;

   interface

   uses
     Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
     Dialogs, AdvShaper, pngimage, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls;

   type
     TAnimation_Form = class(TForm)
       PaintBox1: TPaintBox;
       Timer: TTimer;
       Exit: TButton;
       procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
       procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
       procedure TimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
       procedure ExitClick(Sender: TObject);
       procedure PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
     private
       { Private declarations }
       Image_Counter: Integer;
       Images: array[0..29] of TPNGImage;
     public
       { Public declarations }
     end;

   procedure Run_Animation_Form();
   procedure Finish_Animation_Form();

   implementation

   var
     Animation_Form: TAnimation_Form = nil;

   {$R *.dfm}

   procedure Finish_Animation_Form();
   Begin
     if Animation_Form <> nil then
       Animation_Form.Close;
   End;

   procedure Run_Animation_Form();
   Begin
     Animation_Form := TAnimation_Form.Create(nil);
     Try
       Animation_Form.ShowModal();
     Finally
       FreeAndNil(Animation_Form);
     End;
   End;

   { TAnimation_Form }

   procedure TAnimation_Form.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   var
     I: Integer;
   begin
     for I := Low(Images) to High(Images) do
     begin
       Images[I] := TPNGImage.Create;
       // load PNG image into Images[I] as needed...
     end;

     // FYI, these properties can be set at design time...
     TransparentColor := True;
     TransparentColorValue := Color;
     Image1.Visible := True;
     BorderWidth := 10;
     Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akBottom, akRight];

     Image_Counter := 0;

     ControlStyle := ControlStyle - [csOpaque];
   end;

   procedure TAnimation_Form.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
   var
     I: Integer;
   begin
     for I := Low(Images) to High(Images) do
       Images[I].Free;
   end;

   procedure TAnimation_Form.ExitClick(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     Close;
   end;

   procedure TAnimation_Form.TimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     Inc(Image_Counter);
     if Image_Counter > High(Images) then
       Image_Counter := 0;
     PaintBox1.Invalidate;
   end;

   procedure TAnimation_Form.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     PaintBox1.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, Images[Image_Counter]);
     // or:
     // PaintBox1.Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, PaintBox1.Width, PaintBox1.Height), Images[Image_Counter]);
   end;

   end.
   ```